# ошибка из ниоткуда "(" was not closed

Tags: python

вчера кодил, ошибки не было, сегодня захожу в vsc и вылазит эта ошибка

```
import time

gender = input("кто ты? (1 - мужык, 2 - баба)\n")
name = input("как тя зовут?\n")
age = input("годиков скока?\n")
timetosleep = input("во скока спать ложишься?\n")
broken = input("что чаще всего ломается?\n")
mooha = input("что обычно любят мухи?\n")
phrase = input("напиши любую фразу\n")
imposter = input("как бы ты назвал человека, который предал тебя?\n")
expletive = input("какое ругательство знаешь? обосри меня с головы до ног!\n")
bodypart = input("любимая часть твоего тела?\n")
redobject = input("что бывает красным?\n")
job = input("профессия?\n")
game = input("любимая детская игра\n")
pain = input("что будет собачке, когда ее скинут с 9 этажа?\n")
bad = input("каково обычно после большой пьянки?\n")
missed = input("чего не хватает в твоем доме?\n")
objec = input("любой бытовой предмет\n")
wish = input("чего тебе сейчас хочется?\n")
place = input("место, где не станут искать\n")
dog = input("как зовут твою собаку? если ее нет, то как бы ты ее назвал?\n")
notgoodman = input("нехороший человек - ?\n")

print("Здравствуй Дедушка Мороз! Меня зовут" + str(name) + ". Мне " + str(age) + " лет! Не много не мало, но я верю и надеюсь в то, что ты есть и сейчас читаешь моё письмо. Моя мама очень злая тётя. Она не разрешает писать мне письма тебе, и поэтому я сижу в " + str(place) + "e и пишу это письмо. Мама выпускает меня гулять только до " + str(timetosleep) + ". Когда я её не слушаюсь, она бросает в меня " + str(objec) + " и частенько попадает мне прямо в " + str(bodypart) " =( Однажды я не вытерпел и сказал ей: " + str(phrase) + ". Мой папа работает " + str(job) "ом и приходя с работы с плохим настроением, он кричит: " + str(expletive) "И заставляет меня чинить его " + str(broken) ". Но я не умею ничего ремонтировать, и поэтому у меня получается " + str(mooha) + ". Он злится ещё сильнее, и запрещает мне играть в " + str(game) + "с друзьями. Ещё папа придумал мне кличку, и зовёт меня не " + str(name) ", а " + str(dog) + "! Это очень обидно. В общем, дедушка мороз, если ты не " + str(notgoodman) + ", то ты поймёшь как мне " + str(bad) ". Дорогой Дедушка мороз - " + str(redobject) + ", забери меня к себе или вышли мне " + str(wish) + ". Ещё сделай так, что бы близкие мне люди любили меня и почаще давали мне денег на " + str(wish) + ". Любимый дед мороз, ты мой последний шанс. Я надеюсь на новый год я найду под ёлочкой " + str(wish) + ". Дед Мороз, пойми как мне " + str(bad) + ". Если ты не прочтёшь это письмо или оно не дойдёт до тебя, мне " + str(dog) + ". Помни что я верю в тебя " + str(imposter) + "!")
```

Comment: мне выдало другую ошибку. у вас в нескольких местах не стоит `+`в `print`

Answer (score 3):

Используйте f-string формат, чтобы не путатьтся в таких вещах

```py
a = f"""Здравствуй Дедушка Мороз! Меня зовут {name}. Мне {age} лет! Не много не мало, но я верю и надеюсь в то, что ты ест
ь и сейчас читаешь моё письмо. Моя мама очень злая тётя. Она не разрешает писать мне письма тебе, и поэтому я сижу в {place}e 
и пишу это письмо. Мама выпускает меня гулять только до {str(timetosleep)}. Когда я её не слушаюсь, она бросает в меня {str(objec)}
и частенько попадает мне прямо в {str(bodypart)} =( Однажды я не вытерпел и сказал ей: {str(phrase)}. 
Мой папа работает {str(job)}ом и приходя с работы с плохим настроением, он кричит: {str(expletive)}
И заставляет меня чинить его {str(broken)}. Но я не умею ничего ремонтировать, и поэтому у меня получается 
{str(mooha)}. Он злится ещё сильнее, и запрещает мне играть в {str(game)}с друзьями. Ещё папа придумал мне кличку, 
и зовёт меня не {str(name)}, а {str(dog)}! Это очень обидно. В общем, дедушка мороз, если ты не {str(notgoodman)}, 
то ты поймёшь как мне {str(bad)}. Дорогой Дедушка мороз - {str(redobject)}, забери меня к себе или вышли мне {str(wish)}. 
Ещё сделай так, что бы близкие мне люди любили меня и почаще давали мне денег на {str(wish)}. Любимый дед мороз, ты мой последний шанс. 
Я надеюсь на новый год я найду под ёлочкой {str(wish)}. Дед Мороз, пойми как мне {str(bad)}. Если ты не прочтёшь это письмо или оно не дойдёт до тебя, мне {str(dog)}. 
Помни что я верю в тебя {str(imposter)}!"""
print(a)
```

вы создаете ту же самую строку, но перед кавычками ставите `f`, а в саму строку добавляете только переменные в фигурных скобках вот так `{переменная}`

Добавлю, что нет необходимости, например для числовых типов данных, преобразовывать к строке. Да к тому же, есть классные фичи для вызова напрямую функций `str()`, `repr()`, `ascii()`. [Здесь доки на английском](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

примеры:

```py
>>> string = "STRING"
>>> double = .345
>>> int_num = 123
>>> f"Вот это просто строковая переменная:{string}, а вот это вызов метода repr: {string!r}"
"Вот это просто строковая переменная:STRING, а вот это вызов метода repr: 'STRING'"
>>>
>>> f"Вот это просто float переменная: {double}, но так же можно ее сразу форматнуть вот так  {double:.5f} или вот так {double:.2f}"
'Вот это просто float переменная: 0.345, но так же можно ее сразу форматнуть вот так  0.34500 или вот так 0.34'
>>> 
>>> f"Целое число {int_num} можно не приводить к строке, оно все равно работает корректно" 
'Целое число 123 можно не приводить к строке, оно все равно работает корректно'
```

Comment: Да, этот f-string формат - удобная штука, и есть уже не только в пайтоне, но и похожие конструкции можно писать, например, в C#